# Formatting NSPredicate: Matching "ANY" that match two conditions

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

**I'm a bit at a loss about how to format an NSPredicate where "any" of a certain relationship matches more than one condition.

So for example, say I'm doing a fetch request for an "Employer" entity and I want to get all employers that have at least one employee under age 18. So, I can use `"ANY employees.age < 18"` - simple enough. But say I want to match any that have an employee under 18 who also has the last name "Howser." That is, it's not enough for the employer to match both "any employee under 18" and "any employee named 'Howser'" - they have to have at least one employee that matches both conditions.

How would this predicate be formatted?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is one of the rare circumstances where you need `SUBQUERY`:

```
SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.age < 18 && $e.lastName == 'Howser').@count > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me too. You seems quite experienced, so i am asking: regarding CoreData I have listen of this as a "rare circumstance" from many developer. I don't know, but in my case is just happening so often to check for more attribute value on relationship, I would say that it is instead so rare to check for only one attribute. Do I miss something in my model to avoid this ?